# Django database tables not being created

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So I have an existing project that worked on Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.

I've since tried to run the project under Django 1.9 and Python 3.5.1...

But I'm running into a problem, the tables aren't being created in a new database when I run

`python3.5 manage.py migrate`

Here is the log I'm seeing:

```
[gpsp@localhost gpsp]$ python3.5 manage.py migrate
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/utils.py:37: RemovedInDjango110Warning: You haven't defined a TEMPLATES setting. You must do so before upgrading to Django 1.10. Otherwise Django will be unable to load templates.
  "unable to load templates.", RemovedInDjango110Warning)

/home/gpsp/gpsp/gpsp/urls.py:36: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got loginregistration.views.login). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got loginregistration.views.logout). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got loginregistration.views.register). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got puzzles.views.mypuzzles). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got createpuzzle.views.planning). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got createpuzzle.views.submitplan). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got play.views.request_piece). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got play.views.localplay). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got applicationtester.views.googlemaps). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got applicationtester.views.widget). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

/home/gpsp/gpsp/gpsp/urls.py:42: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
  (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py:89: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got django.views.static.serve). Pass the callable instead.
  t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, sessions, auth
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
[gpsp@localhost gpsp]$
```

Could all of these depreciation warnings prevent the tables from being created?

All the applications are installed in the settings.py.

Comment: how do you know that tables are not created?

Comment: Because I a get Django debug logs telling me the tables do not exist. I've also used a sql database viewer and don't see the tables.

Comment: Django debug logs i.e. the web pages you get when something went wrong with django

Comment: So I learned I have to run `python manage.py makemigrations app_label` for each app installed. But how do I `makemigrations` for all apps?

Answer (score 2):

you first need to create migration files for your apps:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

if you want this to run for all apps:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then migrate those schemes

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**Update**:

you need to insert your apps into `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Can I do `makemigrations` for all my apps?

Comment: @JeffreyHaines sure, just drop the `app_name`

Comment: @JeffreyHaines do you have models in your apps?

Comment: Yes I do... I have about 5 apps with models for each of them.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines 
you need to insert your apps into `INSTALLED_APPS`  did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did that. Something weird I noticed, when i did `makemigrations app1` it made the migration. When I deleted the database, and ran `migrate` it remembered the app... Where do the migration files live? Is it possible my linux os isn't showing the files available without interacting with them first?